# jQuery sortable and AJAX drag and drop by columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a problem with jQuery. I can only drag an item to another column. If I change the order in the same column the element does not bring the id and move to another column it gives id duplication error.

1. Example of how it is

   - Column A - 1, 2, 3, 4
   - Column B - 1, 2, 3, 4
   - Column C - 1, 2, 3, 4
2. How it should be:

   - Column A - 1, 2, 3, 4
   - Column B - 5, 6, 7, 8
   - Column C - 9, 10, 11, 12

Can someone help me ?

```
$(function() {
    var url = 'edit.php';
    $('ul[id^="sort"]').sortable({
        connectWith : ".sortable",
        receive : function(e, ui) {

            var order_id = (ui.item).index();
            var oldIndex = $(this).attr('data-previndex');
            var element_id = (ui.item).attr('id');
            var status_id = $(ui.item).parent(".sortable").data("status-id");
            var task_id = $(ui.item).data("task-id");
            var dNow = new Date();
            var localdate = dNow.getFullYear() + '-' + (dNow.getMonth()+1) + '-' + dNow.getDate() + ' ' + dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes();

            $.ajax({
                url : url + '?status_id=' + status_id + '&ordem_id=' + order_id + '&task_id=' + task_id+  '&time=' + localdate,
                success : function(response) {
                    alert('?status_id=' + status_id + '&ordem_id=' + order_id + '&task_id=' + task_id +  '&time=' + localdate);
                }
            });
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <?php
        $total = mysql_num_rows($query_select_status); 
        if ($total !== 0) {

            while ($dados_categoria = mysql_fetch_object($query_select_status)) {
        ?>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="text">

                            <div data-background-color="rose">
                                <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $dados_categoria->status_name; ?></h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="card-content">
                                <ul class="sortable ui-sortable nav nav-pills-icons nav-pills-rose" id="sort<?php echo $dados_categoria->id; ?>" data-status-id="<?php echo $dados_categoria->id; ?>">
                                    <?php

                                    $query_select_evento = $mysql->sql_query("Select * from ficha_eventos where id_status = $id") or die("Erro T&eacute;cnico:" . mysql_error());

                                    while ($dados_eventos = mysql_fetch_object($query_select_evento)) {

                                    ?>
                                        <li onclick="getPaging(this.value)" class="text-row ui-sortable-handle" data-task-id="<?php echo $dados_eventos->id; ?>">
                                            <?php echo $dados_eventos->id_usuario; ?>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php
                                    }

                                    ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pls post your whole code including HTML, CSS and JavaScript, so we can help

Comment: what I wanted is the same as this example, but updating in php mysql

https://codemyui.com/trello-like-kanban-drag-and-drop-cards-using-scrolling-containers/